# How to start the .Net framework installer silently?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, silent-installer

How to make my C++ Win32 .net-framework installer silent?

I tried sfxmaker software & ussf.exe, but I get an unknown installer error.

Command line arguments /S and /SD did not work for me.

Part of the code I use:

```
if( !CreateProcess( NULL, 
    ".\\InstallationFiles\\dotnetfx 35 SP1 Full.exe /S",
    NULL,
    NULL, 
    FALSE,
    0, 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    &si, 
    &pi ) 
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you tried `dotnetfx 35 SP1 Full.exe /?` ?

The answer is: `dotnetfx 35 SP1 Full.exe /Q` to start the installer silently.

Also beware of the long name with spaces for `CreateProcess`, think about quoting the command name. [`CreateProcess()` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) states :

> If you are using a long file name that contains a space, **use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin**; otherwise, the file name is ambiguous. For example, consider the string "c:\program files\sub dir\program name". This string can be interpreted in a number of ways. The system tries to interpret the possibilities in the following order:
>
> **c:\program.exe** files\sub dir\program name
>
> **c:\program files\sub.exe** dir\program name
>
> **c:\program files\sub dir\program.exe** name
>
> **c:\program files\sub dir\program name.exe**

Comment: if( !CreateProcess( ".\\InstallationFiles\\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe",   
                     /q /norestart",............// first 2 arguments

its not working again the installation asks to check boxes..

Comment: Did you tried to add quotes around the command name or replace the spaces in the .exe name by underscores? You must have a problem related to long name with space. See my addition.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for quiet mode. `/q`. Be careful to check the return code too :)

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390831.aspx) to know more.

Comment: if( !CreateProcess( ".\\InstallationFiles\\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe",   
                     /q /norestart",...........// first 2 arguments

its not working again the installation asks to check boxes..

Answer (score 0):

I got it, Thanks to all,
My solution is:

if( !CreateProcess ( NULL, // No module name (use command line)
".\InstallationFiles\dotnetfx35SP1Full.exe /q /norestart /ChainingPackage ADMINDEPLOYMENT",... // I mentioned only 2 arguments.

Check this too:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390831(v=vs.100).aspx[^]

NOTE: but friends you will not see any improvement on the desk, check task manager to view it.